# Jquery arrow key navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, key

I have these textfield and dropdown menu for a Facebook like autosuggestion:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search_fld"/>

<div id="display">
<div class="display_box">Luca</div>
<div class="display_box">David</div>
<div class="display_box">Mark</div>
<div class="display_box">...</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.display_box:hover
{
  background:#3b5998;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

How can I achieve to pass the 'hover' state  with **down arrow key** from my input "search_fld" to the first 'display_box' and so on for all the "display" divs?

Here is a [link the jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/MKZSE/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't emulate the hover state perfectly.. there's no escape from adding "real" class with the same style:

```
.display_box_hover, .display_box:hover
{
  background:#3b5998;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Now this code will "naviage" the elements:

```
window.displayBoxIndex = -1;

$("#search").keyup(function(e) 
{
        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
        {  
            Navigate(1);
        }
        if(e.keyCode==38)
        {
            Navigate(-1);
        }

});

var Navigate = function(diff) {
    displayBoxIndex += diff;
    var oBoxCollection = $(".display_box");
    if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length)
         displayBoxIndex = 0;
    if (displayBoxIndex < 0)
         displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
    var cssClass = "display_box_hover";
    oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
}
```

This will "remember" the index of the last "selected" element and switch to next or previous element, using the `eq()` function and adding the class from above to that selected element.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKZSE/77/).

Comment: if you did, then, honestly ... it would be much better than mine

Comment: `class` is a reserved name. You have to change that var name or it won't work, at least on jsfiddle. Working version: http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/MKZSE/51/

Comment: @supertrue correct, it was working back when I wrote this probably `class` was marked as reserved at some later point. Didn't get notified of your comment but better late than never! :-)

Comment: I know this is back from 2012 but how would you then select the element on the "Enter" keyboard press?

Comment: @Carlos simple matter of handling the keyCode 13, see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKZSE/144/). Instead of alerting the selected value you can send it via AJAX or anything you want. :)

Answer (score 4):

Sure it's ugly. On fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjKgF/5/).

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(function (){

        $('.display_box').hover(function (){            
            $(this).attr('class', 'display_box current')
        }, function (){
            $(this).attr('class', 'display_box');
        });

        $('#search').keyup(
            function (e){
                var curr = $('#display').find('.current');
                if (e.keyCode == 40) 
                {                                   
                    if(curr.length)
                    {
                            $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');
                            $(curr).next().attr('class', 'display_box current');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#display div:first-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
                    }                   
                }
                if(e.keyCode==38)
                {                                       
                    if(curr.length)
                    {                           
                            $(curr).attr('class', 'display_box');
                            $(curr).prev().attr('class', 'display_box current');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#display div:last-child').attr('class', 'display_box current');
                    }           
                }
            }       
        )

    });
</script>
<style>
.current{
  background:#3b5998;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>

<input type="text" id="search" name="search_fld"/>
<div id="display">
<div class="display_box current">Luca</div>
<div class="display_box">David</div>
<div class="display_box">Mark</div>
<div class="display_box">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Same idea as me, just different implementation. :)

Answer (score 1):

For implementing autosuggestion text field, it would be better to use 'datalist' tag as below:

```
<input list="search" name="search_fld"/>
  <datalist id="search">
     <option value="Luca"/>
     <option value="David"/>
     <option value="Mark"/>
  </datalist>
```

Get more details on datalist tag from here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Answer (score 0):

you may use an arrow key as input field background using css/use an overlay span over the input field with background arrow image and make it visible in hover state  using css or js